# Why the Babel and the Webpack doesn't convert code for ie11

Tags: webpack, babeljs, internet-explorer-11

I try using webpack and babel for convert my code for ie11 but it's doesn't work. Maybe somebody can  help me to find my mistake. I’ll be really appreciate.

here is my **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: '/src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: __dirname + 'dist'
  },
  watch: true,

  devtool: "source-map",

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'babel.config.json'),
            presets: [["@babel/preset-env", {
              debug:true,
              corejs:3,
              useBuiltIns:"usage"
            }]]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  
  
};
```

and this is my babel.config.json

```
    {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "edge": "17",
            "firefox": "60",
            "chrome": "67",
            "safari": "11.1",
            "ie":"11"
          },
          "useBuiltIns": "usage",
          "corejs": "3.6.5"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

And my package.json

```
{
  "name": "module-structure-try",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.9",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "core-js": "^3.24.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
   
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1"
  }
}
```

The webpack  processes and generates files, but the code still does not work in IE11.

Comment: people using ie11 dont deserver internet so i think you can just forget about them

Comment: Less than 0.29% of users worldwide use IE 11 [Source](https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share), and Microsoft withdrew support for it in June this year. Why are you spending time on this?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console in the developer tools? And as already mentioned, IE has been retired with June 15th. I recommend that you can pay more attention to modern browsers such as Chrome, Microsoft Edge.

Comment: There is no any errors webpack working fine, but the code doesn't work in IE11

Comment: What I mean is that do you see any error messages in devtools in IE11?